# Integer to Num conversion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-conversion, typeerror

I was just playing around with Haskell typeclasses and I discovered an error that I am not able to understand.

Here is the code that reproduces it:

```
fun :: (Num a) => Integer -> a
fun a = a + 1
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Integer’
```

Now, as I understand it, Integer is an [instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integer) of the Num Typeclass and Integer type meets all the requirements defined by Num.
Is this kind of conversion not allowed? Isn't this the point of using creating a Typeclass, i.e. 'a' is any instance of typeclass Num.

Comment: In  Haskell there are no implicit conversions: an `Integer` is not automatically promoted to, say, `Double` -- we need to call `fromInteger` to explicitly convert the value. The only exception are numeric literals: `123` is automatically converted to the numeric type the context requires, essentially behaving as if the use wrote `fromInteger (123::Integer)`. All the other expressions (including variables) are not subject to this automatic conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) means that the two operands and the result all have the same type. This thus means that for an expression `a + 1` since `a` is an `Integer`, it means that `1` and `a + 1` are `Integer`s as well.

Your function however promises that for *any* type `a` where `Num a` holds, it can construct a function that maps an `Integer` to an object of that type `a`. So that can be an `Integer`, `Int`, `Double`, etc.

You can make use of the [**`fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`** function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger) to convert the result to any `Num` type with:

```
fun :: Num a => Integer -> a
fun = fromInteger (a + 1)
```